# Changing elements of a constant char* literal in VS

Tags: c++, pointers, char, constants

This is the code:

```
int main()  
{  
    char* a = "abc";    // Should be 'const char*', but no warnings whatsoever on VS
    a[1] = 'e';         // No warnings on VS either 

    std::cout<< a << " " << a[1];  

    return 0;  
}
```

Compiled using gcc version 6.2.0:

```
>g++ -O2 -o Test Test.cpp
Test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
Test.cpp:5:15: warning: ISO C++ forbids converting a string constant to ‘char*’ [-Wwrite-strings]
 char* a = "abc";
           ^~~~~
```

---

```
>./Test
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Compiled using VS 2015.3:

```
>cl /EHsc /W4 /WX /O2 Main.cpp  
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.00.24215.1 for x86  
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.  

Main.cpp  
Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 14.00.24215.1  
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.  

/out:Main.exe  
Main.obj
```

---

```
>Main.exe  
abc e  

HUH?^
```

Compiling without `/O2` yields no warnings either, but crashes on runtime.

Is this a VS compiler bug or I'm missing something?

Comment: [/Zc:strictStrings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn449508.aspx)

Comment: Sigh...anyone knows why this is omitted by default for VS projects?   And can anyone explain why `a[1]` is `e` in the output? Is it a temp?

Comment: @lousybyte The C++ standard is not fully implemented in VS, especially C++11/14 (heck, even C++98 is not fully implemented last I heard!). Maybe they are still using `char* str = "foo";` somewhere, or rely on that behavior for something, or some other obscure reason that doesn't make sense :)

Comment: @Rakete1111 compilers are allowed to offer extensions that don't break conforming programs

Comment: It's common for compilers to default to a mode that is most useful to their user base (as deemed by the compiler vendor), and you have to use various switches for maximum standard compliance mode.  g++ is no different, if you don't use `-pedantic` you get a bunch of extensions (some good, some not-so-good)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do not think this can be called a bug. With `a[1] = 'e';` You are changing the read only memory. String literals are not expected to be modified. This is effectively an undefined behavior. Why VS compiler is not giving a warning, like gcc? Well, every program (compiler is a program either) can be better. In this particular case very old piece of compiler code works because this is not a recent C++ feature (like `T&&` references). Old code may not give out the best error.

There are tons of other ways to write bad code. Unfortunately in C/C++ this is relatively easy. Here we are.

There are numerous static code checkers and sanitizers (ex: [CodeSonar](https://www.grammatech.com/products/codesonar)). Typically they are not free. They catch a lot of problems but not all of them.

Comment: I'm aware you shouldn't modify a string literal, but in a complicated program you could have someone do something like `strcpy_s(a, 4, "xyz");` accidentally and the compiler wouldn't give him any indication that `a` is read only.  Among all the pitfalls and intricacies of C++ I think a compiler should easily catch this kind of unintended behavior by default, and not by enabling some obscure flag.

Comment: If in your example `a` is defined as `char a[4];`, then it will contain a copy of the string literal that can be modified.

Comment: Yes, but if you insert that `strcpy_s` before `cout` in my example, the program will crash at runtime, and the debugger will break at the `cout` instead of at the `strcpy_s` call.  Again, you explained well, I just find it silly that MS chose this default behaviour.